# Firefox and IE cannot execute ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I am using jquery v.3.3 with this Ajax script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'msgs.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { newmsgs:$('#mess').val(),mesuser:$('#mesuser').val()} ,
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is working with Chrome but didn't work with Firefox and IE.

Comment: What does the browser console (F12 in Firefox) say?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast nothing

Comment: Does it submit the form? I mean, like a regular form

Comment: @StyleSh1t yes it is submit form

Comment: What's the point of submitting a form and doing an AJAX request? You'll lose the AJAX response altogether when the page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent the normal `submit` behavior of the browser, using[`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
      e.preventsDefault();  //  <-- This prevents the form submit.
      $.ajax({
        url: 'msgs.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { newmsgs:$('#mess').val(),mesuser:$('#mesuser').val()},
        success: function(){
          location.reload();
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay... In case you want the page to reload... I added `location.reload()` on Ajax success.